In Angular: ERROR ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
I can't figure out why the error is still coming, i declared bootstrap and when debugged bootstrap is defined, does anyone know why its like that, i think its because of bootstrap?
This is my code
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { UserService } from '../../services/service-user/user.service';
import { ModalService } from '../../services/service-modal/modal.service';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/login-response';

declare var bootstrap: any; // Declare Bootstrap for global use

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-login',
  templateUrl: './modal-login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './modal-login.component.css'
})
export class ModalLoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  user: User = new User();

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService, 
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private modalService: ModalService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const modalElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#loginModal');
    this.renderer.listen(modalElement, 'hide.bs.modal', () => {
      this.clearForm();
    });

    this.modalService.showModal$.subscribe(show => {
      if ('open') {
        this.openModal();
      } else if ('close') {
        this.closeModal();
      }
    });
  }

  login(): void {
      this.userService.loginUser(this.user).subscribe({
        next: (response: LoginResponse) => {
          console.log(response),
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.token),
          this.closeModal()
        },
        error: (error) => console.log(error)
      });
  }

  openModal(): void {
    const modalElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#loginModal');
    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalElement);
    modal.show()
  }

  closeModal(): void {
    const modalElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#loginModal');
    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalElement);
    modal.hide();
  }

  clearForm(): void {
    this.user = new User(); // Reset the user model to clear the form
  }
}


This is my angular json, as you can see its corrected imported
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              },
              "src/app/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I already console logged bootstrap and its there, but it still says its undefined

declare a variable:
isBrowser = false;

in constructor:
afterNextRender(() => {
  this.isBrowser = true;
})

you have to use bootstrap in client browser. so put bootstrap in a conditional block wherever you need to use it. for example:
closeModal(): void {
  if (!this.isBrowser) {
    return;
  }
  const modalElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#loginModal');
  const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modalElement);
  modal.hide();
 }

this solution is for angular 17 and 18. if you want use it for older versions you have to use isPlatformBrowser to identify if you are in clinet side or server side.
